# How do I run freestanding scripts with SML/NJ?

Tags: sml, smlnj

How do I use SML/NJ to run a script which reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT say? Is there a way to get rid of the output from the interpreter itself?

Answer (score 3):

Just to be very clear, SML/NJ is not strictly an interpreter.  It's a compiler that just so happens to have a REPL.  The best way to achieve what you're suggesting is to create a heap image (basically a compiled binary that's ready to be loaded by the SML/NJ runtime system), and then run it directly using `sml @SMLload=heapfile.img` where `heapfile.img` is the name of the heap file you generated.  You might also want to pass `@SMLquiet` as a command line option.  This will surpress any output while loading the heap file.

You might also just be trying to compile a program into something you can run stand-alone, in which case you might like to look at the [MLton](http://www.mlton.org) compiler.